# Cannot start Batch service after upgrade to Platform update 32

Tags: windows-services, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

i've upgraded test (onebox) environment to Platform update 32 and i cannot start Microsoft Dynamics 365 Unified Operations: Batch Management Service, there is a warning message that says:
[image]

In event viewer i see the following:

[image]

What i've tried so far:

1) Synchronized and built application from Visual Studio - fine

2) Checked if system is in maintenance mode - it is not

3) Tried to play with "Log on" tab of the service (on behalf of which user service is running) - didn't help

4) Checked if event log is full, cleared, extended allowed space for log twice and let it overwrite itself if it's full - didn't help

P.S. I suggest there is something with database (maybe any issue is enabled/disabled) but i cannot understand which one exactly (cannot find ScaleUnitFeature from event log anywhere).

I cannot restore/delete/replace database because it's important to keep all the data/set up on it

Comment: Did the upgrade go successfully and did you verify all the steps completed in the output?

Comment: yes, i did the upgrade process with the runbook and all steps successfully completed

Comment: Have you checked the enabled features? Just a guess but it says `isScaleUnitFeatureEnabled` and the new features might be the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/fin-ops/get-started/feature-management/feature-management-overview

Comment: The thing is that service is unavailable (i.e. i cannot browse the website) because of batch is being down probably (AOS is running). I've tried to find any feature containing the word 'scale' in database tables which contain the word 'feature' - nothing

Comment: You can stop the batch service and still access D365. That's probably your core problem. I'd look at IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, however, I recently had a situation where I was unable to start the service after attempting some upgrades. What worked for me was opening up the **IIS Manager**, looking at the **Application Pool** menu and starting the *AOSService* application pool. After that, I then started the *AOSService* website under the **Sites** menu.

Hopefully, this helps a fellow D365 developer who has lost their way.